# How to add background image to my menu?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, libgdx

I am currently making some kind of menu in libgdx with a background image. I tried adding the image as an actor but then the buttons did not respond to the touchDown event. So I tried now just drawing with the spriteBatch the background image in the render() method, and after that in the show() method drawing the table and the buttons, but now it only appears the image, no buttons at all. This is the code:

```
   public void show()
{

    // load the texture with our image
    backgroundTexture = new Texture("fonfopiz.png");

    // set the linear texture filter to improve the image stretching
    backgroundTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    // Here we create a region of our texture whose size is 512x301
    backgroundTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, 512, 301);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    crearTablaBack();

    //the general table
    table = super.getTable();
    //table.setFillParent(false);
    Label vacia = new Label("",getSkin());
    table.add(vacia).spaceBottom(45);
    table.row();
    Label lTit;
    try {

        lTit = new Label(res.getString(titulo), getSkin(), "titulos");
        table.add(lTit).spaceBottom(10).spaceLeft(50);
        //stage.addActor(lTit);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    table.row();


  Label lText = new Label(res.getString(titulo + "_TXT"),getSkin());
  lText.setWrap(true);
   table.add(lText).width(375).spaceBottom(55);
   //lText.setAlignment(100);
   //lText.setWidth(200);
   table.row();


   table.setPosition(110, 0);
   //table.setSize(200, 200);


}

public void render(
        float delta )
    {
        super.render( delta );
        batch = super.getBatch();
        // we use the SpriteBatch to draw 2D textures (it is defined in our base
        // class: AbstractScreen)
        batch.begin();

        // we tell the batch to draw the region starting at (0,0) of the
        // lower-left corner with the size of the screen
        batch.draw( backgroundTextureRegion, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() );

        // the end method does the drawing
        batch.end();
    }


private void crearTablaBack() {
    //the table for the back button
    Table tabla = new Table( getSkin() );
    tabla.debug();
    //table.debugTable();

    stage.addActor( tabla );

    tabla.setPosition(40, 35);

     TextButton botonBack = new TextButton( "<<", getSkin() );
     tabla.add( botonBack ).size(60, 40).spaceBottom(20);
      tabla.row();
        botonBack.addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int   pointer, int button) {
               //super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
                System.out.println("back");
                //game.setScreen(new ExperimentosScreen(game));
                //game.setScreen(new PruebaScreen(game));
                return true;
        }

});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont have much idea about scene2d in libgdx but from your code may be if the code of show() method is written in render() method, after drawing your background , then it might work. Wot I am getting is you are drawing the table and buttons and then drawing background above it so all the things are getting hidden by your background. 
One more thing Show method will be called once(the first time you create method your your screen class) and render method will be called many times during life of your class.  And I havnt read your code in depth but have you called stage.draw() or stage.act() anywhere ???

Comment: Ok, after going around in my code I realized that the code I used before(adding the background as an actor) its okey, but I forgot to call to the show() of my superclass.